# Multiply two ImageCollections in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am seeking a method to multiply two ImageCollections with the same number of Images, extent, etc...

I was thinking of a function and a mapping, but the map function only allows for one variable.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/95cb25b4da8c85020359da292801b9c2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the this thread [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360098/google-earth-engine-multiply-an-image-collection-by-a-different-number-dependin);

One way is:

```
 //Import VIIRS nighttime lights
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG");
var nl14 =  imageCollection.filterDate('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01').select('avg_rad')

var cf14 =  imageCollection.filterDate('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01').select('cf_cvg')
var cf14_y = cf14.sum()

var conditional = function(image) {
  return image.divide(cf14_y);
};

var cf14 = cf14.map(conditional)

var ZipCollec = nl14.toList(nl14.size()).zip(cf14.toList(cf14.size()))
print (ZipCollec)

var MultiplyCollec = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  ZipCollec.map(function (ell) {
    ell = ee.List(ell);
    var ImList1 = ee.Image(ell.get(0));
    var ImList2 = ee.Image(ell.get(1));
    return ImList1.multiply(ImList2);
  })
);
print (MultiplyCollec)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The general answer to “how do I do something with images paired up from two collections?” is to use a *join.* But in your case, there is no need to do that. You are *starting* with images from the same collection, but using different *bands* from them. So all you need to do is map over the *original* collection, and select the bands you want to work with only within the map operation. That way all the bands from one image can be worked with together.

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG")
    .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01');

var divisor = imageCollection.select('cf_cvg').sum();

var result = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('avg_rad').multiply(image.select('cf_cvg').divide(divisor));
}).sum();
```

This may not be exactly the computation you intended, as the variable names were a bit confusing, but I hope it illustrates the method. For readability, I recommend that you avoid reassigning variables to different purposes (writing `var nl14 = ...` several times) and instead give each variable a name that reflects what it actually is.